# WCF service encapsulated in a DLL will not work if the service is not referenced in the application

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config, app-config, service-reference

I have a dll that referenced a WCF service (the service is encapsulated into it).

I have a C# application that use the dll, therefore the service is transparent to the application developer.

However, if the application is not referencing the WCF service, it will not work.
I am getting an error:

> "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
 public bool Print(IPrinter printer)
    {
        PrintLabelServiceClient client = null;
        bool isSucceed;

        try
        {
            client = new PrintLabelServiceClient();
            isSucceed = client.Print(TemplateFullFileName, _textFields, _imageFields, printer.Name, printer.Copies);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            client.Abort();
            return false;
        }

        client.Close();

        return isSucceed;
    }
}
```

It fails at line:

```
client = new PrintLabelServiceClient();
```

Is there a way for the application to have the code working without adding the service reference?

- Adding an illustrated explanation:

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to understand.
you have both a reference to the .dll holding PrintLabelService
and a service reference generated by exposing that dll in some remote location, which is how PrintLabelServiceClient class was generated

Comment: Currently to make it work, the application need to reference both the dll and the service. The ideal is to have the application referencing only the dll.

Comment: first of all. if you want to reference only the dll. 
you have to remove the service reference. and write your own Client implementation. 
I'm pretty sure you are not using the Service type from your dll and only the one from the service reference.
what happens if your remove the reference to your dll ?

Comment: I am not referencing the service in my application, this is why I am getting an error. The dll is the only one who knows about the service, it is encapsulated in it

Comment: it seems like there's a big gap in your understanding of how this works.
i can't chat here and explain it all in comment boxes.
if you find a chat room invite me there and i'll explain it

Comment: You might be right but I am not clear why encapsulating my service into a dll result in that I must reference the service into my application too.

Comment: this might be tough to get all at once,
but read this 

 http://blogs.msmvps.com/p3net/2014/02/02/a-smarter-wcf-service-client-part-1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135577/discussion-between-eran-otzap-and-ehh).

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that your reference between the DLL and the service is a service reference and not a binary reference? If so then what you want to do should be perfectly possible.

Comment: @tomredfern, you are correct, this is a service reference

Comment: So what you want to do is perfectly feasible. The information you got in your chat session with eran is incorrect. I don't know why you're getting a nullreference but it is nothing to do with your base approach.

Comment: @eranotzap - there are multiple problems with your comments, such as *if you want to reference only the dll. you have to remove the service reference* - this makes no sense. There is nothing wrong with the OPs approach. It is technically sound.

Comment: @tomredfern, happy to know that my approach was correct but not clear how to fix it

Comment: I think there is a lot mess of misunderstanding here. I ment that  if he wants to remove the service reference he would need to implement his own  client

Comment: And I don't understand why he is referencing his service DLL from the client and then generates a service reference from that same DLL hosted at some remote end point

Comment: @eranotzap - I agree this question was easy to misunderstand and can see how your advice makes sense in the context of what you thought the OP wanted to achieve. However, the reference between the DDL and service is not a binary reference but a service reference.

Comment: @ehh - try to avoid using service references to call services in WCF. Research ChannelFactory<T> instead. I guarantee you this will solve your problem

Comment: Not familiar on this, but definitely will check. Thanks